# Is SMACH still maintained and used?

Tags: ros, executive-smach, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering whether SMACH was stil maintained? Or is this a dying package?

Also is it very much used among the community? Except a few example regarding the PR2 I could not find it used anywhere...

Regards,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197672/is-smach-still-maintained-and-used?/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-11-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-11-18**:
+1 I believe some or many researchers using PR2 use `smach` (I've seen some within the last 1 year) but haven't seen it applied for other robots, although it should be very useful.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanks for your helpful input ;)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-11-18**:
Also I just randomly hit [an email](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2014-August/068829.html) where @Pi Robot used it.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-11-21**:
FWIW, SMACH has been used in many non-PR2 robots.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-21**:
okey dok, I take note. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given that smach is released into Indigo, that's a good sign that it's still maintained.

There are a few open issues, but nothing major. I suspect you could get the maintainer's attention and get a bug fix accepted and released if you found a major bug. That said, smach has been around for many years, and I suspect most of the bugs have been worked out by now; don't confuse a lack of changes for lack of maintenance.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-18**:
Indeed you are right. Now what do you think of it only being used for the PR2, or so? What do the other robots use then?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-18**:
I recently used smach for a project on a turtlebot. There isn't anything PR2-specific about it. It just happens that it was written during the early days of ROS, when most people were developing software for the PR2.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-19**:
Ok, good to know. thanks ;)